# Bash for loop repeat itself to much

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have weird loop issue in bash.

I run this script with 2 images (P1110200.JPG and P1110201.JPG)

The else block need to bee adjusted with other text, I don't think the issue is there

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
output_file="/Users/ralphschipper/temp/test.json"
echo "" > "$output_file" #Clear $output_file

data="[\n"

for file in "$@"; do
    lat=$(/usr/local/bin/exiftool -T -n -c "%.7f" -GPSLatitude "$file")
    lon=$(/usr/local/bin/exiftool -T -n -c "%.7f" -GPSLongitude "$file")

    if [[ ${#lat} -gt 2 ]] 
    then
        geo=$(curl -s "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=geojson&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}" | jq '.features[].properties.display_name')
        data+="{\n\"Name\": \""
        data+=$(/usr/local/bin/exiftool -T -filename "${file}")
        data+="\",\n"
        data+="\"GPS Lat\": \"${lat}\","
        data+="\n"
        data+="\"GPS Lon\": \"${lon}\","
        data+="\n"
        data+="\"Plaats\": $geo\n},\n"
        echo $data >> "$output_file"
    else
        data+=$(/usr/local/bin/exiftool -T -filename "${file}")
        data+="\t"
        data+="-"
        data+="\t"
        data+="-"
        echo $data >> "$output_file"
    fi
done
data+="]" 
echo $data >> "$output_file"
```

The result =

```
[
{
"Name": "P1110200.JPG",
"GPS Lat": "52.2883132547528",
"GPS Lon": "6.71871145124722",
"Plaats": "blah, Nederland"
},

[
{
"Name": "P1110200.JPG",
"GPS Lat": "52.2883132547528",
"GPS Lon": "6.71871145124722",
"Plaats": "Blah Nederland"
},
{
"Name": "P1110201.JPG",
"GPS Lat": "52.2883017118583",
"GPS Lon": "6.71871690304111",
"Plaats": "Blah Nederland"
},

[
{
"Name": "P1110200.JPG",
"GPS Lat": "52.2883132547528",
"GPS Lon": "6.71871145124722",
"Plaats": "Blah Nederland"
},
{
"Name": "P1110201.JPG",
"GPS Lat": "52.2883017118583",
"GPS Lon": "6.71871690304111",
"Plaats": "Blah Nederland"
},
]
```

I think there is a use with the closing ']'
I open the json tag '[' before the loop starts so the loop can read the files

and when the loop stops I close the json tag ']'

I see the closing tag ']' just 1 time in the result, but I see the opening tag '[' 3 times in the results

Can anyone see what's going on?

Comment: You never clear the variable `$data` in your code, you only `data+=` to it.. So each time you do `echo "$data" >> ...` the whole `data` is printed to the file so a new `[` is added....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accumulate the text in `$data`, then `echo $data`  to the file, but you **never** clean $data up, so next time it prints everything again plus the new contents.

Either empty $data after outputting it, or output it just once at the end.

Comment: ahhh now I see it, I cleared the var data at the end and it works now. thanks choroba and KamilCuk. It works now